# Where is parallel gc is used?

Tags: java

Can anyone answer me,please, where is parallel gc usually is used?

I am reading article:

http://blog.takipi.com/garbage-collectors-serial-vs-parallel-vs-cms-vs-the-g1-and-whats-new-in-java-8/

And there is "The parallel collector is best suited for apps that can tolerate application pauses and are trying to optimize for lower CPU overhead caused by the collector".

But which exact examples can be in this case?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all applications can cope with short pauses. Rather than asking what applications can cope with a pause, you should really be asking what applications cannot cope with a pause.

Applications that can't cope with a pause are ones that have to directly interact with the real world and have to do so in real time. Machines and robots are the best example of this. For instance, you don't want the ABS on a car to be paused for a garbage collection when you slam on your brakes in an emergency.

Having said that, a typical example of an application that can cope with a pause is a desktop application. That extra fraction of a second it takes to display a menu or respond to a button click is likely to go unnoticed by the user.